# How to pass a block to an included template?

Tags: symfony, twig

The structure of my Twig files looks like this:

```
- "skeleton_main"
  - includes "skeleteon_header"
  - render "block content"

- "skeleteon_header" should render "block breadcrumb"

- "partial"
  - extends "skeleton_main"
  - fills "block breadcrumb"
```

Now I can output "*block breadcrumb*" in "*sekeleton_main*" but it isn't passed to "*skeleton_header*". How can I access and render the block from within the included template? I tried using `{% include '' with {} %}` but without luck.

```
# skeleton_main
{% include 'header' %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}

# header
{% block breadcrumb %}{% endblock %}

# partial
{% extends 'skeleton_main' %}
{% block breadcrumb %} Breadcrumb {% endblock %}
{% block content %} Content {% endblock %}
```

Maybe there's something wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `include` which does not permit overriding blocks.

Is there a reason to use `include` instead of `extend` ?

Another solution would be to use `embed` which does the same function as `include`, but permits overriding blocks at the same time:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html

Comment: Of course. I don't know, why I didn't think of embed before. Thanks, this works good.

Comment: I'm particularly unintelligent so a working example would be appreciated :)

Comment: The link no longer works - should be https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/embed.html now

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a wrong approch.

You should define `header` as a `block`, not as a separate template.

```
{# skeleton_main #}
{% block header %}
    {% block breadcrumb %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{# partial #}
{% extends 'skeleton_main' %}
{% block breadcrumb %} Breadcrumb {% endblock %}
{% block content %} Content {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I thought about that too. The header is very long, that's why I wanted it to be in another file, to make it easier to maintain. Using embed I can achieve this perfectly. Is there another reason, to not put the header into its own file?